# Android Studio Constantly Shows Error While Creating An Instance of ActivityResultCallback

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I started learning about how I can request app permissions from the Google Documentation. This is basically the code that I'm trying to execute.

```
// Register the permissions callback, which handles the user's response to the
// system permissions dialog. Save the return value, an instance of
// ActivityResultLauncher. You can use either a val, as shown in this snippet,
// or a lateinit var in your onAttach() or onCreate() method.

val requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
            // app.
        } else {
            // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
            // features requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
            // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
            // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
            // decision.
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, whenever I'm trying to write the `registerForActivityResult(...)` part, Android Studio keeps highlighting it as an error.

There's another step that I need to perform along with this. It tells me to add [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#declaring_dependencies) dependency. Even after doing that, Android Studio still shows me that it shows an error. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Can you include the error you're getting? Also do a gradle sync if you haven't after adding the dependency.

Comment: I have synced the Gradle. There's no error. Android Studio autocompletes all functions when we're writing them. Here, it doesn't do the same. And if I'm writing the function on my own, it highlights that part, showing that function is missing.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the following

```
// Kotlin
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-beta01'
```